# Counting Checkboxes on a page of a multipage userforms

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform, multipage

I am attempting to count the number of check boxes that have been checked on a specific page of a userform. I am using VBA with Excel 2010.

This is my code:

```
Public Sub AutoCount()
Dim ctl As control
Dim j As Long

For Each ctl In CharacterBuilder.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Controls' error occurs here
    If TypeOf ctl Is msforms.CheckBox Then
    If CharacterBuilder.Controls(ctl.name).Value = True Then
        j = j + 1
    End If
    End If
Next
CharacterBuilder.Remaining.Caption = j
Unload CharacterBuilder.Skills 'Not sure what this does
End Sub
```

I get the run-time error 459 Object or Class Does not Support the set of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a peculiarity with the **`MultiPage`** control that, unlike most things VBA, its indices are 0-based.

Therefore your second page would be `Pages(1)` and not `Pages(2)`, since `Pages(0)` is the first/default page. If you change your error line to the following:

```
For Each ctl In CharacterBuilder.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls
```

your code should then work.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but I'm not sure that's the issue.
This multipage has six pages (and I was accounting for 0-based indexing). Does this code work on your system?

Could it have to do with the fact that I have this code in a module?

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer: Strange. Yes, it works as expected on my system. I literally just tried it (again!) from a module and it behaved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the reason might be because you haven't defined tour control variable properly.
you could try

```
Dim Ctl as MSForms.control
```